# Can non Jews be buried in a Jewish Cemetery?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave

Can a non Jew be buried in a Jewish Cemetery under any circumstances?

Comment: Why would you think not? Adding your motivation for your question into the question improves the latter.

Answer (score 6):

[Gittin 61](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=61&format=pdf) Says we bury the dead of non-Jews with dead of Jews. (קוברים מתי עכו"ם עם מתי ישראל).
This is *mipnei darkei shalom*

Rashi there comments that the *gemarra* shouldn't be understood as "with" literally, but "also" like we bury our own, **when we find them together**.

Rambam brings *gemarra* down as is.

[Tur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&st=&pgnum=610&hilite=) brings down *gemarra* and Rashi. *Beis Yosef* notes the *Ra"n* that "finding together" in Rashi is *lav davka* and we bury them even if we find only a non-Jew. The *Ra"n* however adds, that we do not bury two people on different levels next to eachother (such as a *tzaddik* by a *rasha*, even a *tzaddik* by a *chassid*) ([SA](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=590) & [Tur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&st=&pgnum=606&hilite=) YD 382) so this should hold the same reasoning (He uses the phrase כל שכן, usually meaning it's a *kal v'chomer*).

[Rambam *evel* 14:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14884) and [SA YD 382](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=593&hilite=) bring the *din* we bury, not entering our current discussion.

[Bach YD 151](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14267&st=&pgnum=493&hilite=) is *medayek* from the *Rambam* that it would be permissable (possibly only referring to the case where they were found together - this point comes and goes and I couldn't understand were it was standing when he reached this part).

According to [this source](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/shut2.asp?id=57415) (son of Rabbi Y.M. Lau) different chief rabbis discussed the matter, ruling to forbid it. I've heard Rav Ovadia gave a similar psak.

[Here](http://www.ateret.org.il/english/torah/view.asp?id=1078) it says Rav Goren allowed it.

Finally Rav Dov Lior answered that if a non-Jew was found buried in a Jewish cemetery - he should be moved. ([non-Jewish grave found in Jewish cemetery](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=29435))

Comment: Why do you assume a gentile is a rasha?

Comment: @DoubleAA, nothing to do with it. He's on a different spiritual level and that's that. Compare [above source](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&st=&pgnum=606&hilite=): "אין קוברין צדיק אצל חסיד מופלג".

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should clarify that in the post, although it's not clear to me that it means spiritual level in an inherent sense or level in terms of his accomplishments. In other words, perhaps a very righteous gentile could be higher than a evil Jew or even a so-so Jew.

Comment: @DoubleAA in some of the sources there is a debate if a _chassid umot ha'olam_ is different from a regular _goy_. At any rate, I wouldn't assume a _goy tzaddik_ would be better than a jew, though corrupt (Note the kal v'chomer in the Bach). But I think this is a whole different discussion :)

Comment: Still not totally clear.  I understand that if found together they can be buried together but Rabbi Gorens case seems to be about someone who thought they were Jewish and maybe this is his reason.  My situation deals with a righteous gentile who has been very involved in his local community who wants to be buried in a Jewish Cemetery

Comment: @MordYisroel That would fit Rav Lau's case.

Comment: We could consider as a hazaka that the non jew used to worship idols.

Comment: "*Rashi there comments that the gemarra shouldn't be understood as "with" literally, but "also" like we bury our own.*" This is also a literal interpretation, and a more plausible one from the context; a simple reading of the gemara does not imply proximate graves.