# May a Jewish cemetery refuse a body?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya

Based on [a recent news item](http://www.cnn.com/2013/05/06/us/boston-up-to-speed/index.html?hpt=hp_c2) wherein cemeteries have been refusing to inter the body of one of the (alleged) Boston bombers, I am curious whether a Jewish cemetery's operators are allowed to refuse to bury a Jew's body that is brought to them, and if so on what grounds? Meaning is it based on the fact that the person was a sinner, and if so which sins warrant this response? Are there other valid reasons?

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21767

Comment: nikmasi, please edit this question so it's not a duplicate of the other. The other asks about non-Jews; maybe tailor this question so it's only about Jews?

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps the Jewish cemetery would need to erect a fence and make a separate portion for the non-Jew. That question asks if it is ever permitted to bury in the Jewish section.

Comment: The operators (who presumably may not be Jewish) or the cemetery itself (which is a Jewish institution)?

Comment: I recommend expanding on the motivation. Instead of just having a context-free link that people have to click on and that may die someday, put a sentence explaining what you saw, and how it motivated the question at hand.

Comment: @DoubleAA both questions ask about burial in a Jewish cemetery, assuming the (IMO) more likely answer to CharlesKoppelman's query. But we can see what nikmasi answers to it.... Meanwhile I'm editing the question myself per my previous comment. Feel free to edit again, obviously, nikmasi.

Comment: @msh210 But according to the opinions in the supposed dupe who allow such burial, can it be forced upon them?

Comment: @DoubleAA hm... Er, nikmasi, is Jew/gentile relevant at all here? I mean, are you asking simply whether a cemetery can refuse a body? If so, why did you mention gentiles? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well if he person was a murderer who got sekila was buried in a separate cemetery,see Sanhedrin.

Answer (score 6):

Per this article at [theyeshivaworld.com](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/General+News/169092/Husband-Who-Kept-Wife-Agunah-Loses-Burial-Rights-in-Israel.html) the Rabanut denied a Jewish burial to a husband who kept his wife an Aguna.

Comment: At least now his wife is free!

Answer (score 2):

The reason I have seen a Jewish cemetery refuse Jewish corpes, is related to money. Specifically, if you don't pay for the plot, they will not bury you.

Since that is apparently a valid excuse, I am assuming that the answer is yes for any reason they want.

Comment: Sad to say, I have also heard of such a requirement in Jewish cemeteries.  The plot must be paid for.  Of course, at the same time, the Jewish community will see to it that a Jew who has died locally and does not own a plot and has no one to provide funds for a plot will receive a proper Jewish burial.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the rules for internment at the New Montifiore Cemetery in Suffolk County, New York, [require](http://www.montefiores.com/newMontefiore/jewish-cemeteries-new-york/regulations.html) that all who buried there are Jewish under Jewish law, and they can deny burial to anyone not fitting that definition.  Many other cemeteries share that position.
  Many cemeteries will also not bury an apostate Jew.  I recall that a Toronto cemetery literally closed its doors on the hearse carrying the body of a Jewish-born Messianic Christian minister.